# Python Threading On Android and IOS

Tags: android, python, ios, multithreading

I'm knee deep in this commercial game and currently working on the in-game chat.  How I code the chat system depends on rather or not threading will work.

My question(s)....

Does anyone know for sure calling a thread on android or ios will result in a separate process and not hold up the app until complete?

This worries me because I came across another python user who was developing some form of app and they stated that their thread did not run as an individual and their app froze up until the thread completed.  (which sucks because python is a cross-platform language)

What I wanna do is have a thread periodically fetch chat data from the server without causing the whole app to pause while doing so.  This will allow for a more professional looking chat system and better user experience.

However, if for some reason python threads will not act as expected, I'll have to use a different logic for the chat system.

I'm sure some of you will probably be like, "just test it" but that's just it....I don't wanna (want to, lol) write all that code just to re-write it all over again if for some reason threading doesn't act right on a phone.

I'm not asking for code here....God knows I can code the hell out of an alien battle cruiser from planet Zars equipped with warp 7.5 engines.

If no one can give me a for sure answer then.... (sigh)......  I'll have to just write the code and cross my fingers in hopes of accurate threading behavior on phones for python programmers or be faced with the devastating task of re-writing a large chunk of code..... on the client and server side!

=====================Update as of July 14 2017==============================

I went ahead and wrote the code anyway.  Turns out the Kivy API set has some back-end issue with creating Rectangle draw instructions in a python thread.  This issue doesn't seem to be relevant when creating widgets from within a thread.

I did find a work around for the draw instruction issues and had things the way I pictured it all but in the end...  I saw more cons than pros in the way I was planning my chat system and decided to re-write it anyway.

The new chat system is easier to work with and I don't have to implement code and fonts for multiple languages. (phew!)

So....looking at my original question now....

Yes,

Python threads will run on their own cpu cycle on an Android phone but what you're trying to accomplish depends on your entire setup...back-end and front end APIs.

I'm surprised to see people assume python can't thread when the language has the modules for threading.

Hell I run threaded processes separate from the main thread all the time on PC.  In fact, I have this nice email app which can generate emails and send out ads/flyers and maintain a valid email database.

The app uses threading to update the UI system so the user of the app knows what's going on in the background.  It's a marketing tool I plan on using later after I release the current app I'm designing now.

I might even release my marketing tool but such a high quality app wouldn't be cheap on the market.  Not when marketing cost so much money.  Being able to reach your target audience at little to no cost...  Sounds too good to be true.

:)

Comment: Have you not heard of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)?

Comment: Most versions of Python are single threaded-  you can't run two threads in it.  They do have some sort of pseudo-threading behavior, but not true threads.  If you need that, pick another language.

Comment: Lmao!  Python supports threading.  Module wise you can use thread or threading; the latter if you're using a class approach.